# Fast way to read last record of Avro file in Java

Tags: avro

Apart from traversing the entire file,is there a fast way of reading the last record? The closest solution I have found is:
There is `seek(long filePosition)` function with `DataFileReader` by which I can directly reach a valid file position and from then onwards, I need to traverse till the end. In this case during every write, I need to update this file position which leads to double writes(one to Avro file, one to update file position). With double writes, comes lots of consistency problems.

Please let me know if any self-sufficient solutin exists. Every record is of variable length.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly your use case, so this solution may not fit your needs (especially since you need to write to the file and read from it again (?)). In my case, I needed to access an .avro file in Java randomly (by key). What I did is to read the whole file when my application is starting and loading it into memory in a HashMap. In this way, the by-key access is O(1). In your case, since you need to access by index (the last), you can use a List instead of a HashMap, and your read will be O(1).

This is to load the file in memory:

```
public Map<String, Height> loadHeights(String... files) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Height> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(String file: files) {
        GenericDatumReader datum = new GenericDatumReader();
        DataFileReader reader = new DataFileReader(new File(file), datum);

        GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(reader.getSchema());
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.next(record);
            map.put(record.get("NETW_ID").toString(), new Height(Integer.valueOf(record.get("CHAINAGE").toString()), Integer.valueOf(record.get("HEIGHT").toString()), Integer.valueOf(record.get("VERTICAL_ERROR").toString())));
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    return map;
}
```

And to read from it with O(1) complexity:

```
private Height getHeightBySegmentId(String segmentId) {
    Height height = altitudes.get(segmentId);
    return height == null ? new Height() : height;
}
```

In your case with the list it will be something like:

```
public List<Height> loadHeights(String... files) throws IOException {
    List<Height> list = new HashMap<>();
    for(String file: files) {
        GenericDatumReader datum = new GenericDatumReader();
        DataFileReader reader = new DataFileReader(new File(file), datum);

        GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(reader.getSchema());
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.next(record);
            list.add(new Height(Integer.valueOf(record.get("CHAINAGE").toString()), Integer.valueOf(record.get("HEIGHT").toString()), Integer.valueOf(record.get("VERTICAL_ERROR").toString())));
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

And to read from it with O(1) complexity:

```
private Height getHeightByIndex(int index) {
    Height height = altitudes.get(index);
    return height == null ? new Height() : height;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, you got the situaion right. There will be dynamic writes happening in the Avro file. There will be some short windows where there will be no write and I will read at that time. 

So every time I read, I need to know the "new last" record. Just once population to a map won't help I guess.